# Groupby column suffix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe:

```
     val1_aa  val1_bb  val2_aa  val2_bb  val2_cc  val3_cc
id                                                       
100        6        0        3        4        3        1
200        0        1        0        0        1        0
300        5        1        1        0        4        0
400        0        3        1        5        7        1
```

I'd like to sum all columns in order of the suffix in each column header. My desired output:

```
     aa  bb  cc
id             
100   9   4   4
200   0   1   1
300   6   1   4
400   1   8   8
```

How do I get this?

---

<sub>Answer posted below.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `groupby` with `lambda` function on `axis=1`

```
In [4178]: df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1], axis=1).sum()  # or x.split('_')[1]
Out[4178]:
     aa  bb  cc
id
100   9   4   4
200   0   1   1
300   6   1   4
400   1   8   8
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know `groupby` could take a lambda. This taught me something new.

Comment: Yea, `by` can be `mapping, function, str, or iterable`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('_(.*)', expand=False), axis=1).sum()
print (df)
     aa  bb  cc
id             
100   9   4   4
200   0   1   1
300   6   1   4
400   1   8   8
```

Another solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df)
    val1    val2       val3
      aa bb   aa bb cc   cc
id                         
100    6  0    3  4  3    1
200    0  1    0  0  1    0
300    5  1    1  0  4    0
400    0  3    1  5  7    1

df = df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()
print (df)
     aa  bb  cc
id             
100   9   4   4
200   0   1   1
300   6   1   4
400   1   8   8
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a `groupby` on the columns.

```
x.groupby(x.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).sum()
```

---

```
x
     val1_aa  val1_bb  val2_aa  val2_bb  val2_cc  val3_cc
id                                                       
100        6        0        3        4        3        1
200        0        1        0        0        1        0
300        5        1        1        0        4        0
400        0        3        1        5        7        1

x.columns.str.split('_').str[1]
Index(['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc'], dtype='object')

y = x.groupby(x.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).sum()

y
     aa  bb  cc
id             
100   9   4   4
200   0   1   1
300   6   1   4
400   1   8   8
```